# Sitecore Experience Analytics Graphs Issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

After upgrading my site from 7.1 to 8.1 I have the following error message appears when opneing any page in the expierence analytics:

"The 'Graph Name' graph cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator."

The following call show 500 error on the browser console:

"http://sitename/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/DC0DB760B0F54690B9EB1BBF7A4F7BD1/all?&dateGrouping=collapsed&&keyTop=8&keyOrderBy=valuePerVisit-Desc&dateFrom=07-04-2016&dateTo=05-07-2016&keyGrouping=by-key"

I checked the log files and there is no server error logged there!

More information:

The error message:
"ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance."

Also

```
     "   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.GetControllerMapping()   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection collector, HttpConfiguration configuration, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider)   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__1()   at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer)   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__0(HttpConfiguration config)   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.ApplyControllerSettings(HttpControllerSettings settings, HttpConfiguration configuration)   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType)   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.GetControllerMapping()   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection collector, HttpConfiguration configuration, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider)

at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__1()   at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer)   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__0(HttpConfiguration config)   at 

System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.ApplyControllerSettings(HttpControllerSettings settings, HttpConfiguration configuration)   at 

System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)   at 

System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType)   at 

Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Dispatcher.NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerDictionary()   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()   at Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Dispatcher.NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.FindMatchingController(String namespaceName, String controllerName)   at Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Dispatcher.NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the response of the call contain more information? If your `customErrors` are off, it probably will.

Comment: I added more information above. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore support provided the cause and solution for this and thought will add it in case same issue happened with someone else:

**Cause:**

It looks like the issue is caused by a conflict in a Web API configuration

As far as I can see, the following code is executed during the application start:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code that runs on application startup
    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(MyDll.WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

**Solution:**

As an alternative approach, this code can be moved to the "initialize" pipeline to run on application startup.

In case if custom code is run after the default Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Pipelines.Initialize.WebApiInitializer processor, the Experience Analytics configuration will be loaded first.

For example:
1) Create the "initialize" pipeline processor

```
internal class WebApiInitializer
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Register);
    }
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

2) Create a config file and place in into the Include/Z.MapRoutes fodler (so it will be loaded last):

```
<configuration xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="HttpAttributeRouting.WebApiInitializer, HttpAttributeRouting" x:after="processor[position()=last()]" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this error is you might be using Web Api in your code. To integrate web api with site core you need to extend your global.asax as below

```
 public class GlobalExtended : Sitecore.Web.Application
{
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ConfigureRoutes);
    }

  public static void ConfigureRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiRoute",
    "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
   }
}
```

You can go through below url for detailed explanation
https://sitecorecommerce.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/webapi-attribute-routing-is-not-working-with-sitecore-7-5/ 
http://blog.krusen.dk/web-api-attribute-routing-in-sitecore-7-5-and-later/

Comment: What makes you think this issue is related to WebAPI integration?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I had face exactly same issue when we are using ASP.NET web api attribute routing with sitecore